# Emma 2.1.5320 can’t read the files written by 2.0.5312

Tags: java, sonarqube, emma

Emma Coverage Issue 
Emma 2.1.5320 can’t read the files written by 2.0.5312 there is an incompatibility issue both ways how do i solve this issue

Comment: Crystal ball broken - any chance you can post the error message(s) you get?

Comment: Emma is abandonware. Consider switching to Jacoco: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/